# R regex delete all numerics except the ones that match this regex

Tags: r, regex

I try to delete all numerics (`[0-9]`) from a character array in R, except if there is a dot before the numbers and up to one number before the dot. I.e. I want to delete all numerics which do **not** match the following regular expression `[0-9]{0,1}\.[0-9]{1,20}`, i.e. if I have

```
test = 'ab 300 0.091% bab 200 x'
```

using `[0-9]{0,1}\.[0-9]{1,20}`, I want:

```
'ab 0.091% bab x'
```

but I fail to see how I can tell `gsub` to drop all numerics but a given regex. Obviously:

```
gsub("[0-9]", "",test)
[1] "ab  .% bab  x"
```

but now the middle part is gone, which I wanted to keep.

Comment: what will be desired result for `10210.123` ?

Comment: Try `gsub("(?<!\\d)(\\d?\\.\\d{1,20})(?!\\d)|\\d", "\\1", test, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all the numbers that do not match your pattern, you could use a capturing group to match what you want to keep and match what you want to remove.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
([0-9]{0,1}\.[0-9]{1,20})|[0-9]+\s*
```

Note that `[0-9]{0,1}` and also be written as `[0-9]?`

**Explanation**

- `([0-9]{0,1}\.[0-9]{1,20})` Capture group 1, match what you want to keep
- `|` Or
- `[0-9]+\s*` Match what you want to remove, 1+ digits followed by 0+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4trkDc/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/EuqDLO)

For example

```
test = 'ab 300 0.091% bab 200 x'
gsub("([0-9]{0,1}\\.[0-9]{1,20})|[0-9]+\\s*", "\\1", test)
```

Output

```
[1] "ab 0.091% bab x"
```

Comment: working solution with great explanation! Could you elabotrate on the meaning/usage of `\\1` in the replacement variable?

Comment: @SAFEX That is the reference to the first capturing group, the part that you want to keep. The opening and closing parenthesis makes `([0-9]{0,1}\.[0-9]{1,20})` the first group. `\\1` means that in the replacement you want to use what is in group 1.

Comment: okay, so `(group1)|(group2)|...` describes capturing group, how would I choose to keep, say group1 and group3? Or how would I replace group2 with not-blank but something else?

Comment: In a replacement you select what you want to replace. If you use an empty string in the replacement, all that is selected including what is in the group is replaced with an empty  string. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/g7sk4P/1) But in this case you don't want to remove group 1 but keep it, so in the replacement you use `\\1` The meaning of `(group1)|(group2)` is group 1 or group 2. The `|` is an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). If you want to keep group 1 and group 3 make sure you match them with a pattern and use `\\1` and `\\3`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `\b` tags like `\b\d+?\b` to eliminate all numerics that don't have a decimal or other characters (or potentially `\b[\d\.]+\b`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub(pattern = "(?<!\\d|\\.)\\d+(?!\\.)\\s?",
     replacement = "",
     x = test,
     perl = TRUE)
#[1] "ab 0.091% bab x"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iaXsMU/1)